# my access token is getting overwritten every time

Tags: jmeter, export-to-csv, beanshell

```
import java.io.*;
import com.opencsv.CSVWriter;
File f= new File("C:\\Users\\Web\\Desktop\\Tokenss.csv");
FileWriter fw= new FileWriter(f);
BufferedWriter bw= new BufferedWriter(fw);
//var rc = prev.getResponseCode();
//ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseHeaders();
String tok = vars.get("Token");
bw.write(tok);
bw.newLine();
bw.close();
fw.close();
```

Question: how to write access_token in CSV always in a new row? It overwrites my access token every time.

Answer (score 0):

You're **overwriting the whole file** each time you call your script, in order to write new line at the end of the file you need change this:

```
FileWriter fw= new FileWriter(f);
```

to this:

```
FileWriter fw= new FileWriter(f, true);
```

where second argument is the [switch for the "append" mode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.io.File,%20boolean))

---

In general [since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so consider migrating to Groovy on next available opportunity. You will either be able to re-use your existing code or simplify it to something like:

```
new File('C:\\Users\\Web\\Desktop\\Tokenss.csv') << vars.get('Token') << System.getProperty('line.separator')
```

See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) article for more information on [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/) scripting in JMeter

Comment: one more thing: How to write in CSV from the second row as it contains column name at top